# Pattern Match "return" value

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Why is it not possible to chain pattern matching constructs?  For instance, the following is legal, if nonsensical,

```
val a = ADT(5)

val b = a match {
  case ADT(a) if a > 4 => ADT(a * 3)
  case ADT(a) => ADT(a + 1)
} 
b match {
  case ADT(a) if a > 13 => doSomething(a)
  case _ => {}
}
```

but the following is not:

```
a match {
  case ADT(a) if a > 4 => ADT(a * 3)
  case ADT(a) => ADT(a + 1)
} match {
  case ADT(a) if a > 13 => doSomething(a)
  case _ => {}
}
```

I suspect it's because I shouldn't be doing it in the first place, but in principle I don't see why it's not legal.

Comment: `(a match { .. }) match { .. }` will work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it should work, because (almost) everything in Scala is an expression and every expression can be used as a pattern match.

In this case the pattern match is an expression, so it can be used by another "chained" pattern match. But the compiler doesn't like it.

Giving the compiler a little hint with parentheses helps:

```
case class ADT(value: Int)

val a = ADT(5)

(a match {
  case ADT(a) if a > 4 => ADT(a * 3)
  case ADT(a) => ADT(a + 1)
}) match {
  case ADT(a) if a > 13 => println(a)
  case _ => {}
}
```

Comment: I stumbled upon the parentheses workaround as well, but I don't understand why it's necessary here but not necessary with something like `val a = if(false) 6 else if (true) if(true) 5 else 3 else 2`

Comment: @CarlSummers the compiler can only infer so much. It's just order of operations. When in doubt (you, or the compiler) get explicit. (I'm new to Scala actually but this is one of the things I love about it.)

Answer (score 5):

Your intuition is correct; it's not nonsense—normally you *would* be able to chain infix operators in such a way, *without parentheses* (as other users have suggested). Indeed, `match` used to be implemented as a method—and worked as an infix operator (left-associative by default)—so your alternate syntax would have worked. However, in Scala 2.5 `match` was made a special language construct instead of a method. I don't know why that was done, but that's the reason: `match` is *not* an infix operator despite seeming so.